# Nullclines for differential equations

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the system of differential equations

$$\dot {x}=y-x^2$$
$$\dot {y}=x-y$$

a. Determine the fixed points

(1,1) (0,0)

b.  Determine the nullclines and the signs of $\dot {x}$ and $\dot {y}$ in the various regions of the plane.

x-nullcline: $y=x^2$

y-nullcline: $y=x$

[image]

Does everything look correct?

Comment: Are you @MathMajor? If not, you could team with this user: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1019337